# Change CommandButton to ToggleButton Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change all my CommandButton in the Userform to ToggleButton. I'm new to stackoverflow and thus I cannot post picture at this moment. I'll try to make it clear.

In the ideal situation, when A is selected, the rest of the toggle buttons will be unselected. Currently I have a lot of these CommandButtons so changing them by deleting and re-coding is burdensome. My question is that are there any methods that can change the CommandButton to ToggleButton without changing the contents?

Comment: Have your used OptionButtons? The "little circle with a dot in it".  Those automatically unselect the others when one is selected.

Comment: You want some code to loop through all the controls on your userform (at design time) and replace the CommandButtons with OptionButtons that display the same caption?

Comment: MatthewD and ChipsLetten - I already had the codes under command button so it was too late to add the optionbuttons. Codes that can change the commandbuttons to optionbuttons will be awesome! Right now I used x.font.bond = true to highligt the selected buttons and it works well so far. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following code to the command button it may serve your purpose.

```
With Application.CommandBars.ActionControl 

.State = Not .State 
End With
```

Comment: It has a run-time error 91 on my code but basically I used the x.font.bold = true to solve the problem. Thanks!